# How to resolve error: Call to a member function initForm() on a non-object in Magento while setting theme?

Tags: magento, themes

I have successfully installed my Magento theme via my admin panel. Now when I try to apply the theme via Magento Admin Panel, I get this fatal error:

```
Call to a member function initForm() on a non-object in
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Edit.php on line 91
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Was the theme installed?

Comment: @MTM Yes. The theme's title shows up in the magento admin panel. But when i click it then Ii get this error.

Comment: Is the compilation enabled?

Comment: @MTM No idea. How would i find that out?

Comment: `system >> tools >> compilation` if its status is enabled, then run to recompile.